# Javascript does wrong calculation in iOS 17.2

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, ipados

I just noticed that JavaScript is doing wrong calculations in iOS 17.2

You can find the sample code on codepen: https://codepen.io/liveman/pen/MWxmyVv

This is the code to calculate the positions:

```
-> please check codepen code, it is to long to paste it here…


/* HELPER METHODS */
    PieContextMenu.setMenuButtonG = function (menu_button_G, id, size) {
        menu_button_G.setAttribute("id", id);
        menu_button_G.setAttribute("class", "pcm_group");
        menu_button_G.setAttribute("transform",
            "translate(" + size/2 + "," + size/2 + ")");
            menu_button_G.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
                PieContextMenu.menu_button_mouseover(this);
            });
            menu_button_G.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
                PieContextMenu.menu_button_mouseout(this);
            });
            // menu_button_G.setAttribute("onclick","deneme()");
            return menu_button_G;
    };

    PieContextMenu.setMenuButton = function (menu_button, radius, stroke_width, index, numberOfButton) {
        menu_button.setAttribute("class", "pcm_button");
        menu_button.setAttribute("r", radius);
        menu_button.setAttribute("stroke-width", stroke_width);

        var perimeter = Math.PI*2*radius;
        var size = (perimeter/numberOfButton)+(perimeter/500);
        var rot = -180+((360/numberOfButton)*index);

        menu_button.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", size + " " + perimeter);
        menu_button.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + rot + ",0,0)");

        return menu_button;
    };

    PieContextMenu.setMenuTitle = function (button_title, text, font_size) {
        button_title.textContent = text;
        button_title.setAttribute("class", "pcm_title");
        button_title.setAttribute("y", "0.35em");
        button_title.setAttribute("font-size", font_size);
        button_title.setAttribute("display", "none");
        return button_title;
    };

    PieContextMenu.setMenuIcon = function (button_icon, icon, radius, index, numberOfButton, font_size) {
        //var cont = PieContextMenu.faviconClassToText(icon);
        var rot = -180+((360/numberOfButton)*index);

        var iconRot = -1*(rot+(180/numberOfButton));
        var dot = PieContextMenu.polarToCartesian(radius, iconRot);
        button_icon.textContent = icon;
        button_icon.setAttribute("class", "pcm_icon");
        button_icon.setAttribute("x", dot.x);
        button_icon.setAttribute("y", -dot.y);
        button_icon.setAttribute("dy", "0.35em");
        button_icon.setAttribute("font-size", font_size);
        return button_icon;
    };

    PieContextMenu.setCenterCircle = function (center, radius, size) {
        center.setAttribute("class", "pcm_center");
        center.setAttribute("r", radius);
        center.setAttribute("transform",
            "translate(" + size/2 + "," + size/2 + ")");
    };

    PieContextMenu.polarToCartesian = function (r, alpha) {
        var rad = alpha * (Math.PI/180);
        var dot = {
            x: r * Math.cos(rad),
            y: r * Math.sin(rad)
        };
        return dot;
    };
```

This example shows a pie menu that opens on a long touch event. The calculation of the menu icons (pcm_icon) does not seem to work anymore, as the icons are in the wrong positions.

[wrong positioning of icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPAPT.jpg)

[correct position of icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoSOM.png)

It worked fine on iOS prior to 17.2. It also works fine on Android and Windows OS.

Is this a WebKit bug (e.g. trigonometric functions) or is there a change in the JS required due to the new WebKit version?

Could you please give me an idea where to look at?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-can-i-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript
READ THIS

Comment: How **exactly** are the calculations "wrong"?

Comment: The icons are displayed in the wrong position, thus I guess the calculation of x and y coordinates is wrong.

Comment: OK well have you checked to see what the computations are actually doing? Like, what the numbers involved actually are?

Comment: I am just wondering why this breaks in iOS/iPadOS 17.2? Is there a known bug? Maybe the provided code in the post does not point out the issue. Please check the code on codepen to see the example.

Comment: I very, very seriously doubt that a bug has been introduced into the way floating point math calculations are carried out.

Comment: I checked the computations. It is getting the right results! Strange...
I added this codepen providing all calculated parameters in an alert: https://codepen.io/liveman/pen/ZEPKbbR?editors=0010
What else might be the root cause for this issue?

Comment: The issue is caused by the used Google icons: 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
Is this malice from Apple towards Google?   
Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?